# T_VARIABLE parse error retreiving results

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have been working on this for a while now and sorted the whole back end out, i'm just struggling with the mySQL database as this is the first time i've used one in a project!
I'm trying to recall some information from a database but from 2 different tables and display it in a loop.
I'm currently getting a T_VARIABLE error whilst trying to recall the information in a loop.

```
<p><?php

$inttotalcredits=0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_products");
$set = mysql_fetch_array($result)
$prod_id = $row[0]

echo "<table border='0' width='100%'>
<tr>
<th>Product ID</th>
<th>Part Name</th>
<th>Part Number</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Level</th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" . "<center> $row[0] </center>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<center> $row[1] </center>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<center> $row[2] </center>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<center> $row[4] </center>" . "</td>";
}

$result1 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_trans WHERE trans_product = $prod_id");
while($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
echo "<td>" . "<center> $row1[6] </center>" . "</td>";
$inttotalcredits += $row1[6];
echo "</tr>";
echo "</center>";
}
echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<b>Total Stock Items</b>" . "</td>";
echo "<td>" . "<b><center> $inttotalcredits </center></b>" . "</td>";

echo "</table>";

?></p>
```

I dont know if this is a straight forward mistake im making or im just not constructing the loop right.

Oliver

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your missing `;` here:

```
$set = mysql_fetch_array($result)
$prod_id = $row[0]
```

Should be:

```
$set = mysql_fetch_array($result);
$prod_id = $row[0];
```

Also as pointed by Lyth you are missing parethesis in while statement:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

Should be:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
```

I suggest also to rewrite your code, to not echo HTML elements in PHP code:

```
<p>
<table border='0' width='100%'>
   <tr>
      <th>Product ID</th>
      <th>Part Name</th>
      <th>Part Number</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Level</th>
   </tr>

<?php
$inttotalcredits = 0;

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM site_products");
$set = mysql_fetch_array($result)
$prod_id = $row[0]

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) :
?>
<tr>
   <td><center><?php echo $row[0] ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo $row[1] ?></center></td>;
   <td><center><?php echo $row[2] ?></center></td>
   <td><center><?php echo $row[3] ?></center></td>
<?php endwhile ?>
```

and so on... It's much cleaner and easier to debug.

Comment: Also:
`while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)`

Missing a closing parenthesis.

Comment: I'm not not getting it echo any results now, is is this something to do with trying to loop from 2 different tables?

Comment: just found the natural join command. This makes things a lot easier!